# Arduino crashes only if I set the time

Tags: time, arduino

I'm VERY puzzled and was hoping that someone here could provide some sanity.

I have a fairly elaborate Arduino sketch that is responding to scheduled events 
at the time designated in the event. In order to do this I have setup a loop that examines  a queue of events and checks the event time to see if it matches the current time. I also have code in the loop that checks the current temp and sends a serial message with a timestamp.

I noticed that it is no longer running for more than 10 - 15 minutes before it crashes (goes silent). I assumed it was some of my code, so I started commenting out pieces until it started working again... I was astounded to find that it only started working (ran for 14+ hours) after I removed the call to setTime()!

I can't understand how a call to the setTime() library function would cause a crash 10 minutes later. I assumed that this was a very stable library...

Any ideas would be welcome!

```
if(timeStatus() != timeSet) {
    if (processSyncMessage()) {;
        Serial.println(F("Time sync completed.\n"));
    }
    else {                        // Time sync failed for some reason, resend request.
        Serial.println(F("Waiting for sync message\n"));
    }
}
else {  // time is set.
...
```

I have 'simplified' the following routine to remove the serial message receipt and parsing to further isolate the problem...

```
int processSyncMessage() {
// if time sync available from serial port, update time and return true
     Serial.println(F("Processing time sync message"));
     time_t pctime = 1371118147;
     setTime(pctime);   // Sync Arduino clock to the time received on the serial port
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Further examination of the serial output has revealed 4-5 BELL codes (0x07) as the last thing received from the Arduino. Implying that it is requesting a resync, but I can find no further information about this "function". The example implies that this is used on the NTP version, but doesn't address resync with the serial supported time sync.

Comment: Here is the answer, although I don't understand the mechanism. I must have accidentally copied the syncProvider() code along with the rest of the example clock code. This is where the BELL codes were coming from. As soon as I removed this call form the setup() code everything became stable again. I just don't seem to understand why that would cause the board to crash. I see nothing in the library that jumps out at me that would have this effect... Any ideas anyone?